# Chrome Extension Vs Website's Content-Security-Policy "object-src 'self' blob:"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm writing a chrome extension that makes use of an `<object>` in the content script that loads content from my central server to display to the user. On some websites, my attempt at setting the `data` attribute on the `<object>` is blocked, with the following error:

```
Refused to load plugin data from 'https://redacted.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Ffirefox%2F' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' *.mozilla.net *.mozilla.org *.mozilla.com". Note that 'object-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

My extension works without issue on stackoverflow.com! Note, sometimes it's `object-src 'self' blob:` instead.

From the response headers of the website my extension is trying to load on, it's clear that that's what is stopping my extension from being able to do what it does (these headers are missing from stackoverflow.com which is why it works):

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' *.mozilla.net *.mozilla.org *.mozilla.com; child-src www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com www.youtube-nocookie.com trackertest.org www.surveygizmo.com accounts.firefox.com accounts.firefox.com.cn www.youtube.com; script-src 'self' *.mozilla.net *.mozilla.org *.mozilla.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com tagmanager.google.com www.youtube.com s.ytimg.com; style-src 'self' *.mozilla.net *.mozilla.org *.mozilla.com 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' *.mozilla.net *.mozilla.org *.mozilla.com data: mozilla.org www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com adservice.google.com adservice.google.de adservice.google.dk creativecommons.org ad.doubleclick.net; frame-src www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com www.youtube-nocookie.com trackertest.org www.surveygizmo.com accounts.firefox.com accounts.firefox.com.cn www.youtube.com; connect-src 'self' *.mozilla.net *.mozilla.org *.mozilla.com www.googletagmanager.com www.google-analytics.com https://accounts.firefox.com/ https://accounts.firefox.com.cn/
```

Is there a way around this? Would Shadow DOM be an option? I've already attempted to add `content_security_policy` to my `manifest.json` but this will never work because the browser is respecting what the parent website responded with in it's headers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way is to rewrite the site's Content-Security-Policy HTTP header using a blocking chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived listener, the examples should be easy to find. However if there's another extension that modifies CSP too, it may override your extension's value. Also, some sites may embed the CSP value in a `<meta>` header though so it'll be quite harder to modify in Chrome so just hope you don't need it.

Comment: @wOxxOm that did it. Pretty powerful stuff, this webRequestBlocking permission. Thanks again.